# SPF for zoho mail servers

Tags: spf

I have zoho domain mails. for Spf verification Icreated
as pe their instruction as follow as.
name : @.vernia.in
Text
"v=spf1 include:zoho.com ~all"

and saved. But on verification it says "We are unable to get TXT record for SPF right now"
The mail server provider says "it's dns problem. 
as an search result answer I aterered the record set as

"v=spf1 ip4:35.188.21.196 -all"

but the same failure result I got.
Please help me.

Comment: I thaks for yuors kind attentions and answers of my problem. Yours answer may be absolutely right, but my problem is I can't create text record vernia.in without any prefix, because I already have one text record without prefix. When I try to create without prefix, it reject to save. Please with this difficult situation, advice me a solution to solve. Once again thaks for yours help.

Answer (score 1):

DNS changes must be published for it to work.

From a linux server, open a terminal and type:

```
dig vernia.in txt
```

Currently the only result is:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
vernia.in.      300 IN  TXT "google-site-verification=Bcdec9mMz2adyhWgM5rV2I_PwIxFcDPUnJSuXUsGIi8"
```

As you can see, you don't have currently published the SPF records.

You should add a line like this one to your DNS file:

```
vernia.in.  IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:zoho.com ~all"
```

And increase de DNS serial number in SOA section before publishing.

Answer (score 1):

@ is a commonly used to represent the root, EG: vernia.in, depending on your DNS provider try adding the txt to the root of the domain so it is vernia.in rather than @.vernia.in.

Comment: I thaks for yuors kind attentions and answers of my problem. Yours answer may be absolutely right, but my problem is I can't create text record vernia.in without any prefix, because I already have one text record without prefix. When I try to create without prefix, it reject to save. Please with this difficult situation, advice me a solution to solve. Once again thaks for yours help.

Comment: Yes, also with G suit tools, I found that it is not published.

Comment: The google site verification is only required when adding the site for the first time. You should be able to safely remove it

Comment: I tried to add this text record to my domain mail server spf verification.

Comment: I tried to add this text record to my domain mail server spf verification. But an idea clicked me, I added this record with previously created record that is without any prefix as additional. It passed verification successfully. I heartily thanks to everyone who answered me.